# Button on AlertDialog android.support.v7.app not visually disabled on old android versions

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I've created an AlertDialog with a positive button on it using android.support.v7.app and even though the button is not enabled using setEnabled(false) the button doesn't appear as a disabled.
 I've tried it in Kit Kat and it does work but it doesn’t in Android 4.1.1 for example. Is there any bug known?

Comment: Please add your code - do you use different layouts for different APIs?

Comment: This happens to me as well, this is how I enable and disable `AlertDialog` buttons: `((AlertDialog) this.getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);`